# JQuery validate: validator.elementValue is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two fields in my form which I want one of them to be filled. I've found a `JQuery validate` plugin but `require_from_group` seems not working.

Console in inspect returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: validator.elementValue is not a function
```

The first thing I did is append class to desired fields `grouprequired`.

Now I have JS file; the `short_description` and `language_from` validation worked perfectly until I've added checking `text_to_translate` and `file` validations.

Do you know where is the problem?

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });

    $("#job_creation_form").validate({
        rules: {
            short_description: {
                required: true
            },
            language_from: {
                required: true
            },
            text_to_translate: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.grouprequired']
            },
            file: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.grouprequired']
            }
        },

        messages: {
            short_description: {
                required: "Short description can't be empty. Please fill this field."
            },
            language_from: {
                required: "Please choose current language."
            },
            text_to_translate: {
                require_from_group: "Either fill this form with a text or attach a file (below)."
            },
            file: {
                require_from_group: "Either attach a file or fill text to translate (above)."
            }
        }
    });
    $.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function (value, element, options) {
        alert('kosd')
        var $fields = $(options[1], element.form),
            $fieldsFirst = $fields.eq(0),
            validator = $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") ? $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp") : $.extend({}, this),
            isValid = $fields.filter(function () {
                    return validator.elementValue(this);
                }).length >= options[0];

        // Store the cloned validator for future validation
        $fieldsFirst.data("valid_req_grp", validator);

        // If element isn't being validated, run each require_from_group field's validation rules
        if (!$(element).data("being_validated")) {
            $fields.data("being_validated", true);
            $fields.each(function () {
                validator.element(this);
            });
            $fields.data("being_validated", false);
        }
        return isValid;
    }, $.validator.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));
});
```

Before the red line in console, there is this:

```
jquery.validate.min.js:29 exception occured when checking element id_text_to_translate, check the 'require_from_group' method TypeError: validator.elementValue is not a function(…)
```

EDIT: This is an actual HTML of the form:

```
<form id="job_creation_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate"><input
        type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="249lrU6KpGBGmDp7ezM7ApU3jGLOvBnY">


    <div id="div_id_short_description" class="control-group"><label for="id_short_description"
                                                                    class="control-label requiredField">
        Short description<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class="controls"><input class="textinput textInput" id="id_short_description" maxlength="40"
                                     name="short_description" type="text">
            <p id="hint_id_short_description" class="help-block">Very short description of this order</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_language_from" class="control-group"><label for="id_language_from"
                                                                class="control-label requiredField">
        Language from<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class="controls"><select class="select" id="id_language_from" name="language_from">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="45">Slovak</option>
            <option value="46">Russian</option>
            <option value="47">Magyar</option>
            <option value="48">English</option>
            <option value="49">Croatian</option>
            <option value="50">Spanish</option>
            <option value="51">Dutch</option>
            <option value="52">Estonian</option>
        </select></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_text_to_translate" class="control-group"><label for="id_text_to_translate" class="control-label ">
        Text to translate
    </label>
        <div class="controls"><textarea class="grouprequired textarea" cols="40" id="id_text_to_translate"
                                        name="text_to_translate" placeholder="Specification" rows="10"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_file" class="control-group"><label for="id_file" class="control-label ">
        File
    </label>
        <div class="controls"><input class="grouprequired clearablefileinput" id="id_file" name="file" type="file">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_notes" class="control-group"><label for="id_notes" class="control-label requiredField">
        Notes<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
        <div class="controls"><textarea class="textarea" cols="40" id="id_notes" name="notes" rows="10"></textarea>
            <p id="hint_id_notes" class="help-block">Notes</p></div>
    </div>


    <input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="5"><input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS"
                                                                                           name="form-INITIAL_FORMS"
                                                                                           type="hidden"
                                                                                           value="0"><input
            id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0"><input
            id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="5">

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="249lrU6KpGBGmDp7ezM7ApU3jGLOvBnY">
    <label for="id_form-0-language">Language:</label><select class="select-language" id="id_form-0-language"
                                                             name="form-0-language">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="45">Slovak</option>
        <option value="46">Russian</option>
        <option value="47">Magyar</option>
        <option value="48">English</option>
        <option value="49">Croatian</option>
        <option value="50">Spanish</option>
        <option value="51">Dutch</option>
        <option value="52">Estonian</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_form-0-level">Level:</label><select id="id_form-0-level" name="form-0-level">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="34">Unknown</option>
        <option value="35">Standard level</option>
        <option value="36">Professional level</option>
        <option value="37">Native speaker level</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="249lrU6KpGBGmDp7ezM7ApU3jGLOvBnY">
    <label for="id_form-1-language">Language:</label><select class="select-language" id="id_form-1-language"
                                                             name="form-1-language">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="45">Slovak</option>
        <option value="46">Russian</option>
        <option value="47">Magyar</option>
        <option value="48">English</option>
        <option value="49">Croatian</option>
        <option value="50">Spanish</option>
        <option value="51">Dutch</option>
        <option value="52">Estonian</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_form-1-level">Level:</label><select id="id_form-1-level" name="form-1-level">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="34">Unknown</option>
        <option value="35">Standard level</option>
        <option value="36">Professional level</option>
        <option value="37">Native speaker level</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="249lrU6KpGBGmDp7ezM7ApU3jGLOvBnY">
    <label for="id_form-2-language">Language:</label><select class="select-language" id="id_form-2-language"
                                                             name="form-2-language">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="45">Slovak</option>
        <option value="46">Russian</option>
        <option value="47">Magyar</option>
        <option value="48">English</option>
        <option value="49">Croatian</option>
        <option value="50">Spanish</option>
        <option value="51">Dutch</option>
        <option value="52">Estonian</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_form-2-level">Level:</label><select id="id_form-2-level" name="form-2-level">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="34">Unknown</option>
        <option value="35">Standard level</option>
        <option value="36">Professional level</option>
        <option value="37">Native speaker level</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="249lrU6KpGBGmDp7ezM7ApU3jGLOvBnY">
    <label for="id_form-3-language">Language:</label><select class="select-language" id="id_form-3-language"
                                                             name="form-3-language">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="45">Slovak</option>
        <option value="46">Russian</option>
        <option value="47">Magyar</option>
        <option value="48">English</option>
        <option value="49">Croatian</option>
        <option value="50">Spanish</option>
        <option value="51">Dutch</option>
        <option value="52">Estonian</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_form-3-level">Level:</label><select id="id_form-3-level" name="form-3-level">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="34">Unknown</option>
        <option value="35">Standard level</option>
        <option value="36">Professional level</option>
        <option value="37">Native speaker level</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="249lrU6KpGBGmDp7ezM7ApU3jGLOvBnY">
    <label for="id_form-4-language">Language:</label><select class="select-language" id="id_form-4-language"
                                                             name="form-4-language">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="45">Slovak</option>
        <option value="46">Russian</option>
        <option value="47">Magyar</option>
        <option value="48">English</option>
        <option value="49">Croatian</option>
        <option value="50">Spanish</option>
        <option value="51">Dutch</option>
        <option value="52">Estonian</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_form-4-level">Level:</label><select id="id_form-4-level" name="form-4-level">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="34">Unknown</option>
        <option value="35">Standard level</option>
        <option value="36">Professional level</option>
        <option value="37">Native speaker level</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button value="Update" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't see the relevant markup in that picture.  However, please never post a picture of markup... only the actual code.  It's difficult to read, impossible to copy/paste, and the content bypasses the SO search.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me, so it must be someplace you did not show us (see my previous comment).  Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/2k8bmdcx/

Comment: Ok Sparky, I've removed the image and posted a code (bottom of the question). Hm.. that's weird. I have this in head <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>// <script src="{% static  "js/functions.js" %}"></script> Maybe there is a problem with this.

Comment: `<script src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/… src="{% static "js/functions.js" %}"></script>` doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: Edited. There is this line: '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>' and this '<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>' and this '<script src="{% static "js/functions.js" %}"></script>' which refers to the file with the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304349/jquery-validate-validator-elementvalue-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment62132625_37304349):

> `<script src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/…`

So you're using version 1.9 of the jQuery Validate plugin along with what appears to be the `require_from_group` method copied out of version 1.15 of the plugin's `additional-methods.js` file.  Many bugs within `require_from_group` have been fixed since version 1.9 and the version of a method from `additional-methods.js` needs to match the jQuery Validate version.

Upgrade the jQuery Validate plugin to version 1.15

```
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"
```

Otherwise, it's working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/s40kwon6/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that 1.15.0 is newer than 1.9.

Comment: @Milano, `15` is greater than `9`.